# How to show keyboard done button in multiline text in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm having a multiline text in my react native view. When user types , in keyboard view I need to show done (tick mark) button. Instead of that it shows next line icon. Is there any way to achieve this. If I use text input I can do that , but I need multiple lines to be added. This is my text input

```
<TextInput style = {styles.contactInput}
           underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
           multiline = {true}
           placeholder="Type your feedback here"/>
```

Comment: The done button on the keyboard? Sorry, not entirely sure what you're looking for.

Comment: Are you looking to change the 'return key'? If so, there is a [prop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#returnkeytype) for it

Comment: @MC10 thanks. Your comment's link was broken but the URL pointed me in the right direction, so I made an answer out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add blurOnSubmit={true} in order to show the submit button rather than the return key

```
<TextInput style = {styles.contactInput}
           underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
           multiline = {true}
           blurOnSubmit={true}
           placeholder="Type your feedback here"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The comment by @MC10 points in the right direction, but the link in his comment doesn't work anymore.

The React Native TextInput has a few [different return key types](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#returnkeytype). I quote below from the official docs page

> Determines how the return key should look.
>
> Cross platform
>
> The following values work across platforms:
>
> ```
> done
> go
> next
> search
> send
> ```

So, depending on what you want your return key to look like and do, you should be able to choose one of the above values. There are other OS specific values as well which you can read in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

multiline input is meant to be multiline, meaning that you need enter key to create a new line, for that reason, you cannot change enter key to anything else